# Java file input not working after compile

Tags: java, file-io, jar, compilation, embedded-resource

so I trying to import a file that's in my res folder, so far I have been using this method.

```
File f = new File("src/resources/levels/" + part + "/" + filename + ".txt");
```

But after I compile it and run it as a jar it no longer works, I understand this is because its looking for the file on the disk instead of the jar, I had the same problem with importing my images and font but I managed to fix that but after researching and I just can't find a different way. I'm not getting any errors when I run the jar, instead the information just doesn't show up, and this is compiling and running fine in eclipse.

This is my resource file:

```
package scrolls;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class Resources
{
    static BufferedImage[] textures = new BufferedImage[8];
    static BufferedImage[] mapTextures = new BufferedImage[9];
    static BufferedImage texture;
    static BufferedImage[] waterAnimated = new BufferedImage[64];
    static BufferedImage water;
    static BufferedImage icon;
    public static Font f, fs;
    static int imageCounter = 0;

    public Resources()
    {
        textures();
        createArray(texture, textures, 32, 1, 8);
        createArray(water, waterAnimated, 32, 64, 1);
        getFont();
        buildMapTextures(textures, mapTextures);
    }

    public static void counter()
    {
        imageCounter++;
        if (imageCounter >= 500)
            imageCounter = 0;
        //System.out.println(imageCounter / 8);
    }

    private void buildMapTextures(BufferedImage[] textures, BufferedImage[] mapTextures)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            mapTextures[i] = resize(textures[i], 3, 3);
        }
        mapTextures[8] = resize(waterAnimated[2], 3, 3);
    }

    private BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int newW, int newH)
    {
        BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, newW, newH, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public static BufferedImage waterAnimation()
    {
        return waterAnimated[imageCounter / 8];
    }

    private void textures()
    {
        try
        {
            texture = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/resources/textures.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            water = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/resources/water.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            icon = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/resources/icon.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

    }

    static BufferedImage player()
    {
        BufferedImage player = null;
        try
        {
            player = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/resources/player.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        return player;
    }

    static void createArray(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage[] images, int size, int rows, int cols)
    {
        BufferedImage temp = image;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                images[(i * cols) + j] = temp.getSubimage(j * size, i * size, size, size);
            }
        }
    }

    void readLevel(String filename, int[][] level, int part)
    {
        try
        {
            File f = new File("src/resources/levels/" + part + "/" + filename + ".txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte b = 0;
            while ((b = (byte) in.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append("" + ((char) b));
            }
            String str = sb.toString();
            String[] lines = str.split("(\n|\r)+");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].length(); j++)
                {
                    level[i][j] = Integer.parseInt("" + lines[i].charAt(j));
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getFont()
    {
        try
        {
            f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Jet Set.ttf"));
            fs = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Jet Set.ttf"));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        f = f.deriveFont(22f);
        fs = fs.deriveFont(13f);
    }
}
```

So how would I import my file so it can be read when compiled into a jar?

Comment: `/src` won't be available at runtime (was you move out of the IDE).  It sounds like you are using Eclipse, I believe Eclipse allows you to create a `resources` folder while will automatically be included with your program, you should move your resources to it (if your not, then don't worry).  The path should look more something like `/resources/levels/" + part + "/" + filename + ".txt"`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I created a resources package and keep all my stuff in there, /reresources..... works fine with the other stuff like images and font I'm importing, but it doesn't work with txt files.

Comment: But why is it stored in the `src` directory?

Comment: Should I put it outside the src? Ill try that I didn't think it would make much of a difference.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer eclipse

Comment: Then yes, the `resources` directory shouldn't be the `src` directory.  Once you build you application, the `src` directory will not be part of the final output, hence the path will not exist.  As Andrew has already stated, embedded resources need to be read via `Class#getResource` API, not the `File` API

Answer (score 1):

Swap the `FileReader` for an `InputStreamReader` something like this..

```
URL urlToText = this.getClass().getResource(
    "/resources/levels/" + part + "/" + filename + ".txt");
InputStream is = urlToText.openStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with .openURL, "The method openURL() is undefined for the type URL"

Comment: See edited answer.  BTW - a quick inspection of the JavaDocs might have solved it for you.  That should be the first place to check..

Comment: Im getting a different error now, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from InputStream to InputStreamReader"

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, if I change from InputStreamReader to InputStream, that messes up BufferedReader, and if I change that that messes something else up and so on. It there any other way to get this to work?

Comment: *"I can't seem to get this to work"*  Again, the JavaDocs would help there.  Programming does not work by magic, you need to learn how to read and use the documentation.  See the 2nd edit that has now been seen to compile locally (after the ImgScalr stuff was edited out).  The path might still not be right, but this is the direction to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The src folder shouldn't be inside the jar, it should be next to the jar file, and use absolute path.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getabsolutepath.htm

EDIT:

```
    public void install() throws IOException {
        String absolutePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
            JarFile Jar = new JarFile(new File(absolutePath + "/jarName.jar"));
            extractJar(Jar, absolutePath + "/src/");
}

    public void extractJar(JarFile jar, String dest) throws IOException {
            java.util.Enumeration enu = jar.entries();
            while (enu.hasMoreElements() == true) {
                java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enu.nextElement();
                java.io.File f = new java.io.File(dest + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                if(!f.exists())
                {
                    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                }

                if (file.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
                    f.mkdir();
                    continue;
                }
                java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
                java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
                while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
                    fos.write(is.read());
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: In eclipse when I export as Executable Jar thats how it makes my jar.

Comment: The nature of a 'levels .txt' indicates it is an application resource which would typically be delivered as an **embedded resource** that cannot be accessed by `File`.

Comment: then you would have to use JarOutputStream extract it pro grammatically, then you can reference the folder that it is extracted to.

Comment: decompiling the jar seems like a lot of work just to get the file.

Comment: I know, but it is a way to do it. dont have to use it.